# Redirect user back to sitecore logout page instead of Azure AD login page

Tags: federated-authentication, login, azure-ad

I'm using Sitecore 9.3

Currently, I have configured the Sitecore to bypass the Sitecore identity provider login page by following as per the [doc](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/sitecore-experience-manager/en/use-the-sitecore-identity-server-as-a-federation-gateway.html) but Is there a way to redirect the user to the logout page after sign out from the content editor instead of taking directly to Azure AD?

Expected behavior: User enter sitename/sitecore/login -> Azure AD Login Page -> sitecore content editor -> Log out -> Sitecoe log out page

Actual behavior: User enter sitename/sitecore/login -> Azure AD Login Page -> sitecore content editor -> Log out -> Back to Azure AD login page

Options tried:

1. I have tried setting the signout page but there is no luck from that.
2. Found that we can configure PostLogoutRedirectUrl from the Sitecore documentation but wasn't sure where to configure.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way I achieved this task is by creating a custom pipeline and processor where  the `RedirectUrl` is set to the desired page by following this [article](https://bigredmachine.github.io/post/federated-authentication-single-sign-out/)

Answer (score 0):

PostLogoutRedirectUris configuration exists inside `[Identity server root\sitecore\Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityServer\Config\identityServer.xml]` file, Try and set that to redirect to your Sitecore logout page.

Make sure to restart the Identity server after updating the XML file

Comment: I added the post logout redirect uri {AllowedCorsOrigin}/login/shell/sitecoreidentityserver / {AllowedCorsOrigin}/identity/signin but none of them worked and instead I started seeing 502.5 error.